# How to I resolve my ARM Template deployment template path having a space?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-bicep

I have a DevOps classic release pipeline that is trying to deploy a bicep file.

The bicep file is from an artefact from a previous pipeline. The template path is "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Build Azure Function artefact/deploy/main.bicep" as can be seen from the picture.

[image: pipeline]

When I run it I'm getting error

```
    2023-06-02T08:20:27.2917878Z ##[section]Starting: ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope
2023-06-02T08:20:27.3103349Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-02T08:20:27.3103555Z Task         : ARM template deployment
2023-06-02T08:20:27.3103646Z Description  : Deploy an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template to all the deployment scopes
2023-06-02T08:20:27.3103788Z Version      : 3.223.1
2023-06-02T08:20:27.3103858Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-06-02T08:20:27.3103979Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment
2023-06-02T08:20:27.3104133Z ==============================================================================
2023-06-02T08:20:28.1836169Z ARM Service Connection deployment scope - Subscription
2023-06-02T08:20:28.2044804Z Checking if the following resource group exists: demoCreateResourceGroup.
2023-06-02T08:20:29.0181056Z Resource group exists: true.
2023-06-02T08:20:29.0183902Z Creating deployment parameters.
2023-06-02T08:21:11.2676519Z ##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
2023-06-02T08:21:11.2691310Z ##[error]Error: Command failed: az bicep build --file D:\a\r1\a\_Build Azure Function artefact\deploy\main.bicep
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: Azure Function artefact\deploy\main.bicep
```

That last line is indicating to me that it's trying to run the az bicep command, but it's not sanitising the spaces in my template path. I've tried "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Build%20Azure%20Function%20artefact/deploy/main.bicep" and this doesn't seem to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Update your source alias to use the value without spaces:

[image]

and update your template path again.